# Part of Javascript loop doesn't work when a single variable is changed

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, for-loop, if-statement

I am an absolute beginner in Javascript and I am trying to build a table by looping through my data. It works as intended, but as soon as I change the variable `myVersion` to `2` instead of `1`, the cells in the first column are no longer filled with the values in `alternatives` but state `undefined`.

**What I am trying to achieve is that the loop checks for the value of `Version` and only use the corresponding data.**

It works fine with `myVersion = "1"`, which I just can't wrap my head around :D And all the other columns are filled correctly...

Please ignore the values in `myData`, they have no meaning as of right now :)

As I am a beginner, I am thankful for any tips and tricks to improve my code besides the question asked here.

Thanks in advance!

Here is a [link](https://jsfiddle.net/kovaroi/wfx1u0yk/1/) to fiddle with the code:

```js
function createDCE() {
  var alternatives = ["Car","Bike","Train"];
  var myVERSION = "2";
  
  var myData = [
    { "Version":"1","Task":"1","Concept":"1","Att1":"Banane","Att2":"5€","Att3":"27,56","Att4":"$$$","Att5":"50°C"},
    { "Version":"1","Task":"1","Concept":"2","Att1":"Karotte","Att2":"10€","Att3":"58,87","Att4":"€€€","Att5":"165°F"},
    { "Version":"1","Task":"1","Concept":"3","Att1":"Banane + Karotte","Att2":"10€","Att3":"58,87","Att4":"€€€","Att5":"165°F"},
    { "Version":"2","Task":"1","Concept":"1","Att1":"Banane","Att2":"5€","Att3":"27,56","Att4":"$$$","Att5":"50°C"},
    { "Version":"2","Task":"1","Concept":"2","Att1":"Karotte","Att2":"10€","Att3":"58,87","Att4":"€€€","Att5":"165°F"},
    { "Version":"2","Task":"1","Concept":"3","Att1":"Banane + Karotte","Att2":"10€","Att3":"58,87","Att4":"€€€","Att5":"165°F"}
    
  ]
  
  var col = [];
  col.push("Option");
  for (var key in myData[0]) {
    if (key != "Version" && key != "Task" && key != "Concept") {
      col.push(key);
    }
  }
  col.push("Buttons here");
  
  var table = document.createElement("table");
  var tr = table.insertRow(-1);
  
  for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
    var th = document.createElement("th");
    th.innerHTML = col[i];
    tr.appendChild(th);
  }
  
  for (var i = 0; i < myData.length; i++) {
    if (myData[i]["Version"] === myVERSION) {
      tr = table.insertRow(-1);
      for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
        if (j == 0) {
          var createLabel = tr.insertCell(-1);
          createLabel.innerHTML = alternatives[i]; // This is what doesn't seem to work anymore when "myVersion" is anything but "1"...  
        }
        else {
          var tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
          tabCell.innerHTML = myData[i][col[j]];
        }
      }
    }
  }
  
  var divContainer = document.getElementById("dce_table");
  divContainer.innerHTML = "";
  divContainer.appendChild(table);
}

createDCE();
```

```html
<table id="dce_table"></table>
```

Comment: `createLabel.innerHTML = alternatives[i];` this line has prob, bcz i value is like 3, 4, 5 which index not exist in your `alternatives` array

Comment: So, I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to achieve with the ```alternatives``` but when ```myVersion="2"``` the value for ```i``` is 3, 4 or 5 which are the indexes for the objects in the array with ```Version:2```

Comment: Thank you so much, that clears things up. Any idea on how to make it work so that the "alternatives" are alway added to the first column, no matter the value of "myVersion"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `alternatives` array has 3 values, with index 0, 1, 2.

Your `myData` array has 6 values, with index 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.

When you loop over `myData` (`for (var i = 0; i < myData.length; i++)`), as the first 3 values have `Version: 1` they have indexes 0, 1, 2 which map to the indexes of the `alternatives` array. Your next 3 values, with `Version: 2`, have indexes 3, 4, 5 which don't exist in the `alternatives` array, causing it to return `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

There is an index error in the loop. Your version 2 indexes are greater than 2 and alternatives array has max index 2 so when you changed the version 2 index i  of mydata is becoming 3 4 5 and these indexes not exists in alternatives array.

hope i can tell the problem.